# How find the length of an array

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**Story:**

In fact this question is related to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115905/generating-an-array-of-partially-random-boolean-values-based-on-certain-criteria/35116430?noredirect=1#comment57964600_35116430).

How to create an array maintaining following conditions-

```
1.Total - 10
2.Won   -  7
3.Lost  -  3
4.Longest Winning Streak - 5
5.Longest Losing Streak - 2
```

Now I need to generate an array of random boolean values (`true` representing a win and `false` representing a loss) which fulfills the above criteria.

So, in this case the output can be any of the following:

```
0011011111
1111101100
1010011111
..........
```

**Question:**

***I created a script that showed me that under above conditions array length will 112 [see](http://pastebin.com/FmXc4Zhw) at best.***

How to know what will be the length of this array when `Total`,`Won` and `Lost` value is changed- better a general rule based on the chnaging values of all the 5 values/conditions mentioned above.

Comment: For the particular case:Let's call the longest winning streak W and longest losing streak L. Then W is a sequence 11111 and L is 00 that leaves us with 2 more 1's and a single 0. Now arrange the set $\{W,L, 1, 1, 0\}$ in such way that W is surrounded by zeros.

Comment: @user26977  then how will you get 112 for the above conditions?

Comment: Can we interpret the win/loses as sum of kind of a game that is we are playing 10 distinct games in which $5$ consecutive results should be a win ...etc..etc...and all that is there in the question...

Comment: @Freelancer Nops not any condition out of the mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular case:Let's call the longest winning streak W and longest losing streak L. Then W is a sequence 11111 and L is 00 that leaves us with 2 more 1's and a single 0. Now arrange the set $\{W,L,1,1,0\}$ in such way that W is surrounded by zeros.

You have 2 possibilities $LW0$ and $0WL$. For the remaining 1's you have 3 possibilities (put both in front, put both in the end, or 1 in front and 1 in the end). This gives you total of 6 possibilities.

The general case can be treated similarly, take the winning streak, put loses around etc, but the number of branches will grow quickly. You can start with $L$ if it is longer then $W$ as well.